# How to check in Python3.2 if a string has any numbers using regex

Tags: python, regex, numbers

I need to write a script where one can type their name (via input) and the script has to check if the name has the right format (no numbers, no Capslock, starting with the capital letter). This is what i have so far:

```
import re

def inputName():
  name = input("Enter your name: ")
  if re.search('^[A-Z]{1}\w[a-z]+',name):
    print("ok")
  else:
    print('not ok')

inputName()
```

I've also tried [^\d] and \D and [^0-9] but it still doesnt work correctly. When I enter "A8hkjh" it returns "not ok", nut when I type "Ahj8k" it returns "ok", even though there is a digit in the string.

How can I make the script check the whole string?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w` matches letters as well as digits and underscores. Also, don't forget to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the regex to the end of the string, otherwise it will succeed on a partial match. For example, on `"Ab1"`, the substring `"Ab"` is matched by your regex if you don't use the `$` anchor:

```
 re.search('^[A-Z][a-z]+$',name)
```

should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

username = "john"

result = re.search(r'.*?(?!.*?(\d|[A-Z]))', username)

if result.groups()[0] is None:
    print "{} passed validation".format(username)
```

The regex: `.*?(?!.*?(\d|[A-Z]))` will match anything as long as it has no digits or capital letters in it, as requested.

Comment: I think that's a little bit too complex for my school, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: What part is complex? It's about the same as your example

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you want to check the whole string, you need to anchor to the beginning of the string AND the end.  You have an anchor to the beginning with `^`, but you should anchor to the end with `$`.  Your regex `^[A-Z]{1}\w[a-z]+` is only checking the first few characters of the string which is why Ahj8k returns valid.  It is also very naive in that it will not handle names like "McDonald", "Smith-Jones", "Jackson Jr." or "de Icaza". Were I to write a regex for a name, I'd keep it simple and permissive: `^[A-Za-z\.\s\-]+$`.

Comment: Hmm yeah I can enter Jr. and stuff now, but i cannot enter for example "Alina"...

Answer (score 0):

The mistake that you made is that \w take the digit.

Try this : [regex101](http://regex101.com/)

it's a pretty cool website to test your regexp

```
import re

def inputName():
     name = input('Enter your name: ')
     if re.search("^[A-Z][a-z]+$", name):
         print('ok')
     else:
         print("not ok")
```

This code works, for :

> $>Enter your name: Ahj8k
>
> Not Ok